# Phone Battery Lifespan

Tags: battery-charging

In order to prolong a battery lifespan, can a mobile phone (or a laptop) be programmed to charge up to a maximum level of less than 100%?

Comment: Why do you think it will prolong it's lifetime?

Comment: Yes, but not by the end consumer. It is a decision made by the pack designer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Lithium-ion batteries don't like being float charged, or forced to stay at a full state of charge all of the time. Keeping them at, say 4.1 V per cell instead of 4.22 V per cell can have an impact on cell longevity.

One of the laptops that I own has a BIOS option to only charge the battery to 80 %. I use it.

Same story with one of my e-cigarettes, of all things. You can choose between two different maximum charging voltages.

Whether *you* can reprogram your own laptop or a phone, however, depends entirely on two things:

- The design of the device. Some devices have this option, most do not. In principle, all devices can conceivably be hacked to allow for this option. Which leads us to the second point:
- The skill of the one trying to do the change. Changing a BIOS setting is relatively easy, but if the device design doesn't have that option, and is proprietary and locked down, you would need pretty good hacking skills to pull it off.

Comment: The thing is that the 100% you see on your phone or laptop is not necessarily the 100% of the battery.

Comment: True, but with consumer electronics, most of the time, it's pretty close. Consumers seem to prefer a long use time between charges over a long lifetime of the product. Or at least, manufacturers seem to assume that consumers prefer that. Makes sense: The consumers get to buy (consume) new stuff soon, and the manufacturers earn money, and everyone is happy. So they maximise the charging voltage. Which is why my phone is currently starting to suck. With electric cars it's better, luckily. They typically aim for a longer service life at the cost of range.